# Percona/XtraDB storage volumes

Tags: mysql, xtradb

One of Percona Server with XtraDB's main benefits is enhanced scalability over regular MySQL. Does anyone know how the data stored on disk for a given table compares between Percona/XtraDB and MySQL, i.e. is the same table stored in each system bigger, smaller or the same in Percona/XtraDB? I have a feeling it's the same, but would like to know for certain and haven't been able to find any relevant info.

I've only started looking at Percona/XtraDB, so trying to gather some info on it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same (unless you explicitly enable extra features).

Source: I work for Percona.

Answer (score 0):

Since XtraDB is an enhanced version of InnoDB, I would expect it to have a larger size. Never used XtraDB but since its a fork of InnoDB, it'd expect it to be such.

Btw what is regular MySQL ? MyISAM storage engine ?

Comment: Thanks for that Srattrav. Hopefully will get a more certain answer!

To answer your question, MySQL uses MyISAM by default, but you can specify InnoDB if you want. In fact, as of MySQL 5.5, InnoDB becomes the default storage engine.